hot water system overflows after repairs
Our water system was making a thudding noise when we ran the tap. Called a plumber and they installed a hammer arrester, which fixed the thudding.
However, we now get a large amount of water coming out of the hot water system’s overflow valve and pipe over night, where previously there was never more than a drizzle. Called the plumber back and they changed the valve, which did nothing.
The plumber is now saying the amount of water overflowing (at least a few liters every night) is perfectly normal, so there is nothing to be done. They’ve re-routed the overflow pipe to vent over a drain, but so much water comes out so fast that it splashes all over the place, drenching the ground and the wood paneling behind the vent. We’ve had to place a bucket under it which we have to empty daily.
Just looking for any advice about what can be done here. Is this amount of overflow really to be expected?!? Why has this only started after installing the hammer arrestor? Any other solutions?

is there an expansion tank?

That amount of water coming out of the "overflow" indicates the water heater is overheating perhaps boiling the water. Is the water coming out the kitchen faucet or the bathroom lavatory scalding hot? What country is this? Was the "valve" that was changed the pressure-temperature relief valve? Is this a tank water heater or a tankless?

Further component to replace us your plumber. This is not "normal"; he's incompetent

I would see if reducing the temperature on the thermostat/s help.  Maybe they are set to the highest setting?
